# Google Chrome Sync behind a firewall

Tags: google-chrome

The firewall in my company is configured with some to stringent rules. When I am connected through this network my synchronization fails. In other networks all works fine!

How works Google Chrome Sync? What are the Internet addresses used during synchronization? What rules do I add in the firewall for this to work? It's important for me, I need this to propagate some Chrome policy through Chrome users.

Answer (score 1):

Google requires HTTPS to authenticate your profile with their servers.  If not, syncing will not work.  Make sure your firewall rules arent blocking port 443.